# Typescript: type alias with both call and construct signatures- not working

Tags: typescript

I am getting acquainted with Typescript after 3 years, seems alot of stuff to crunch. One thing I am not able to workout yet is how to implement `call signature` and `construct signature` on either a type alias or an interface.

If I write code like below, I get below compile time error:

`Type 'typeof personType' is not assignable to type 'PersonType'. Type 'typeof personType' provides no match for the signature '(name: string, age: number): Person2'.ts(2322)`

Could you guys please help on this?

Thanks in advance.

```
type PersonType = {
    new(name: string, age: number): Person2;
    (name: string, age: number): Person2;
  };
  
  interface Person2 {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  }
  
  const personType: PersonType = class implements Person2 {
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number) {}
  };
  
  const john = new personType("John", 25);
  console.log(john); // { name: 'John', age: 25 }
```

Comment: Remove the call signature..?

Comment: @pink - As I mentioned, I want both call signature and construct signature on my func type.

Comment: Modern JS doesn't let you call class constructors, so your code also has a runtime error if you actually wrote `const john = personType("John", 25)`.  Hence the compile error is correctly warning you of a mistake you're making.  If you want something different you'll need to implement it differently, like maybe a wrapper function to convert class constructors into something that's also callable, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJV0VW). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - thanks for your answer, it seems too much to crunch. I initially took the example from this typescript official example. Too bad, in many of their examples, they show the scenarios but don't provide implementations.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "it seems too much to crunch" means.  If I write up an answer explaining why there's an error (JS class constructors are, in fact, not callable at runtime) and how to possibly work around it (e.g., proxying the class constructor so if someone calls it like a function it returns an instance instead of throwing a runtime error), would you accept it?  If not, why not?